# Annotation Javascript library is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, annotations

I did install annotorious from the [githab](https://github.com/annotorious/annotorious/releases/tag/v2.7.12) and created a html file and copy the code on [documentation](https://annotorious.github.io/getting-started/), but nothing happened it just show the image without annotorious .
here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="annotorious.min.css">
      </head>
      
      <body>
        <div id="content">
          <img id="hallstatt" src="640px-Hallstatt.jpg">
        </div>
        <script>
          (function() {
            var anno = Annotorious.init({
              image: 'hallstatt' // image element or ID
            });
      
            anno.loadAnnotations('annotations.w3c.json');
      
            // Add event handlers using .on  
            anno.on('createAnnotation', function(annotation) {
              // Do something
            });
          })()
        </script>
      
        <script type="text/javascript" src="annotorious.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="annotorious.umd.js.map"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="recogito-polyfills.js"></script>
      </body>
</html>
```

and you can see here that i have all the files in the same directory:

```
Directory of C:\Users\YCH\Desktop\test_annotation

03/11/2023  12:42    <DIR>          .
03/11/2023  12:42    <DIR>          ..
03/11/2023  12:41             7 368 640px-Hallstatt.jpg
03/11/2023  14:18            10 311 annotorious.min.css
03/11/2023  12:52           286 326 annotorious.min.js
03/11/2023  12:36         1 055 483 annotorious.umd.js.map
03/11/2023  14:16               937 index.html
03/11/2023  12:36           161 729 recogito-polyfills.js
```

I test the css(by changing the body color) and JavaScript(by console.log) both configured with the html file still nothing working

Comment: Could you explains where're the  required json file ? it seems that it requires another json file to run function ? ```anno.loadAnnotations('annotations.w3c.json');```

Comment: also you need to add some part of code here 
```anno.on('createAnnotation', function(annotation) {
              // Do something
            });
```
replacing Do something ?

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman I guess //doSomething is to override the function but i can't even configure the basic first , and for annotations.w3c.json its file library will create it and save in it the zones that been defined in the image.(i check the github specified in the documentation and there is no json file )

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are running your demo page by opening the HTML file in your browser.

When reaching the line that says `loadAnnotations`, your code attempts to fetch a JSON file. That's something that browsers don't allow due to cross origin security policies if you load the page from a file. Instead you'd need to serve the page from the web, or via a development server. (See below.)

If you look into your browser console, you'll probably see an error for the `loadAnnotations` line. If you comment that out, you should get annotation functionality working.

To load the annotations from the JSON file, serve your working directory with a dev server like [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).